# how to work BETWEEN query by dates in Crystal Report usingvb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

Can someone help to edit this `RecordSelectionFormula`? It's giving an error, something with date format...

Date value from database is:

```
data type = datetime (yyyy-mm-dd)
```

and

```
datetimepicker is formatdatetime(now,vbshortdate)
```

And my code-snippet is:

```
"{tblTimeLog.dtr_name}='" & cboName.Text & "' and 
{tbltimelog.dtr_datelog} Between '" & DateValue(DateTimePicker1.Text) & 
"' AND '" & DateValue(DateTimePicker2.Text) & "'"
```

The first line of my code (`dtr_name to cboname`) is correct; I've checked it. But I think the problem is from filtering the date..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query as

```
"{tblTimeLog.dtr_name}='" & cboName.Text & "' and {tbltimelog.dtr_datelog}
in '" & DateValue(DateTimePicker1.Text) & "' to '" & 
DateValue(DateTimePicker2.Text) & "'"
```

Comment: and now, i got no error.. but the new problem is.. result = 0 (it's like .count = 0 from DB) even though it has 3 records with the date between to values.. (i have listview to show result).. thank you..

Comment: Use date field as  {tbltimelog.dtr_datelog } in date ('" & DateTimePicker1.Text.ToString("yyyy,MM,dd") & "' ....  You need to use Date() funtion to pass values in crystal report from SelectionFormula... whatever values you get from DateValue(DateTimePicker1.Text) , you have to convert them in "yyyy,MM,dd" format..

Comment: so you mean the location or arrangement is not equal to DB records.. i try.. i guess it is now working..

Comment: sir got new error..  failed to retrieve data from the database
database vendorcde: 241